# How do I run a specific goal with a particular configuration in a Maven plugin when I have several configurations for that goal

Tags: maven, plugins, maven-2, pom.xml

See plugin config from pom.xml below.

I can do:

`mvn myplugin:myGoal`

Which runs myGoal (both executions I suppose) but I want to be able to choose either the first or the second executions independently.

I know I can add an id to the execution element, but how do I refer to that id on the command line. I'd like to get to something which does what this imagined command does:

`mvn myplugin:myGoal --executionId=1`

Is this possible, or am I going about this the wrong way?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.myplugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>myplugin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process-cats</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>myGoal</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <myParam>cats</myParam>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>process-dogs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>myGoal</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <myParam>dogs</myParam>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Would you mind accepting http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627949/318054? The previously accepted answer is not valid anymore.

Comment: Agreed, the accepted answer "No, not possible" is incorrect. You can mvn plugin:goal@an_id now.. So if you had an <id>an_id</id> it would work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I can do `mvn myplugin:myGoal` 
> Which runs myGoal (both executions I suppose)

None of them (assuming they had unique `id`). Executions are bound to a phase, you need to run the given phase to trigger them.

> I know I can add an id to the execution element, but how do I refer to that id on the command line.

Not supported. What is possible for plugins invoked on the CLI is to define a **non global** configuration in the POM using the special `default-cli` `executionId`, like this:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-cli</id>
      <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

> Is this possible, or am I going about this the wrong way?

No, not possible. Either pass the parameters on the command line or use profiles (with or without the above default execution).

#### References

- [Default Plugin Execution IDs](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Default+Plugin+Execution+IDs)
- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3203
- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3401

Answer (score 60):

Execution of multiple goals from the CLI is now supported in Maven 3.3.1+

```
mvn exec:java@first-cli
mvn exec:java@second-cli
```

Where first-cli/second-cli are the execution ids.

[Apache Maven 3.3.1 Features](https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2015/03/2015-03-17-apache-maven-3-dot-3-1-features/)

For your example the commands would be

```
mvn myplugin:mygoal@process-cats
mvn myplugin:mygoal@process-dogs
```

Comment: FYI: I tried to do `mvn maven-compiler-plugin:compile@process-annotations` but it yield "No plugin found for prefix 'maven-compiler-plugin'" but this works:
`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile@process-annotations`

Answer (score 15):

Hey you can create your goal like this:-

```
org.myplugin:myplugin-maven-plugin:1.1.1:myGoal  i.e
<groupId>:<artifactId>:<version>:<yourgoal>
```

It works in my case ...

Comment: yes. and if you are in multi-module project, then do not forget to add -pl my-module

Answer (score 3):

The assumption you made that if you call

```
  mvn myplugin:myGoal
```

But the problem is that you will get an error message cause the execution have no unique id's (both in this case have the same).

You can reach what you like to do via profiles which you can activate via mvn -PXYZ and mvn -PABC