# Debugging "Incorrect configuration of jOOQ code generation tool"

Tags: maven, code-generation, jooq

I am trying to follow along with the jOOQ tutorial. I am at [Step 3](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/getting-started/tutorials/jooq-in-7-steps/jooq-in-7-steps-step3/) (code generation) but want to do the code generation step using Maven.

Here is the contents of my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.hiew</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Specify the maven code generator plugin -->
                <!-- Use org.jooq            for the Open Source Edition
                         org.jooq.pro        for commercial editions,
                         org.jooq.pro-java-6 for commercial editions with Java 6 support,
                         org.jooq.trial      for the free trial edition

                     Note: Only the Open Source Edition is hosted on Maven Central.
                           Import the others manually from your distribution -->
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.2</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jooq-codegen</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Configure the database connection here -->
                            <jdbc>
                                <driver>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                                <url>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/library</url>
                                <user>root</user>
                                <password>mysql</password>
                            </jdbc>

                            <generator>
                                <!-- The default code generator. You can override this one, to generate your own code style.
                                     Supported generators:
                                     - org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator
                                     - org.jooq.codegen.ScalaGenerator
                                     Defaults to org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator -->
                                <name>org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator</name>

                                <database>
                                    <!-- The database type. The format here is:
                                         org.util.[database].[database]Database -->
                                    <name>org.jooq.meta.mariadb.MariaDBDatabase</name>

                                    <!-- The database schema (or in the absence of schema support, in your RDBMS this
                                         can be the owner, user, database name) to be generated -->
                                    <inputSchema>library</inputSchema>

                                    <!-- All elements that are generated from your schema
                                         (A Java regular expression. Use the pipe to separate several expressions)
                                         Watch out for case-sensitivity. Depending on your database, this might be important! -->
                                    <includes>.*</includes>

                                    <!-- All elements that are excluded from your schema
                                         (A Java regular expression. Use the pipe to separate several expressions).
                                         Excludes match before includes, i.e. excludes have a higher priority -->
                                    <excludes></excludes>
                                </database>

                                <target>
                                    <!-- The destination package of your generated classes (within the destination directory) -->
                                    <packageName>net.hiew.jooqtutorial.generated</packageName>

                                    <!-- The destination directory of your generated classes. Using Maven directory layout here -->
                                    <directory>/home/james/src/local/jooqtutorial/src/main/java/</directory>
                                </target>
                            </generator>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My project directory:

[image: project directory]

The error I get when running `mvn -e jooq-codegen:generate`:

```
[INFO] --- jooq-codegen-maven:3.11.2:generate (default-cli) @ jooq-tutorial ---                                                                                                                              
[ERROR] Incorrect configuration of jOOQ code generation tool                                                                                                                                                 
[ERROR]                                                                                                                                                                                                      
The jOOQ-codegen-maven module's generator configuration is not set up correctly.                                                                                                                             
This can have a variety of reasons, among which:                                                                                                                                                             
- Your pom.xml's <configuration> contains invalid XML according to jooq-codegen-3.11.0.xsd                                                                                                                   
- There is a version or artifact mismatch between your pom.xml and your commandline
```

The error message is not that helpful, so I am not sure of the best way to debug the problem further. The `pom.xml` validates and the database exists and is accessible as described in the `<configuration>` element.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The configuration tag has to be directly under the plugin tag, not inside execution:

```
<plugin>
  ...
  <executions>
     ...
  </executions>

  <configuration>
     ...
  </configuration>
  ...
</plugin>
```

Full plugin tag:

```
<plugin>
  <!-- Specify the maven code generator plugin -->
  <!-- Use org.jooq            for the Open Source Edition             org.jooq.pro        for commercial editions,             org.jooq.pro-java-6 for commercial editions with Java 6 support,             org.jooq.trial      for the free trial edition         Note: Only the Open Source Edition is hosted on Maven Central.               Import the others manually from your distribution -->
  <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
  <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
  <version>3.11.2</version>

  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>jooq-codegen</id>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
      <version>${mariadb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <configuration>
    <!-- Configure the database connection here -->
    <jdbc>
      <driver>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</driver>
      <url>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/library</url>
      <user>root</user>
      <password>mysql</password>
    </jdbc>

    <generator>
      <!-- The default code generator. You can override this one, to generate your own code style.                     Supported generators:                     - org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator                     - org.jooq.codegen.ScalaGenerator                     Defaults to org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator -->
      <name>org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator</name>
      <database>
        <!-- The database type. The format here is:                         org.util.[database].[database]Database -->
        <name>org.jooq.meta.mariadb.MariaDBDatabase</name>
        <!-- The database schema (or in the absence of schema support, in your RDBMS this                         can be the owner, user, database name) to be generated -->
        <inputSchema>library</inputSchema>
        <!-- All elements that are generated from your schema                         (A Java regular expression. Use the pipe to separate several expressions)                         Watch out for case-sensitivity. Depending on your database, this might be important! -->
        <includes>.*</includes>
        <!-- All elements that are excluded from your schema                         (A Java regular expression. Use the pipe to separate several expressions).                         Excludes match before includes, i.e. excludes have a higher priority -->
        <excludes>
        </excludes>
      </database>
      <target>
        <!-- The destination package of your generated classes (within the destination directory) -->
        <packageName>net.hiew.jooqtutorial.generated</packageName>
        <!-- The destination directory of your generated classes. Using Maven directory layout here -->
        <directory>/home/james/src/local/jooqtutorial/src/main/java/</directory>
      </target>
    </generator>

  </configuration>

</plugin>
```

Note tha you may need to specify your mariadb version in the dependency, I added the defalut variable name.

Comment: Thanks! This got a bit further. Now it spits out a different error: `Error running jOOQ code generation tool: Error generating code for catalog: Error writing /home/james/src/local/jooqtutorial/src/main/java/net/hie
w/jooqtutorial/generated/DefaultCatalog.java: /home/james/src/local/jooqtutorial/src/main/java/net/hiew/jooqtutorial/generated/DefaultCatalog.java (No such file or directory)`. I created the full path to where `DefaultCatalog.java` should be generated but it's still failing in the same way.

Comment: @JamesHiew seems just an error in relation to the target path, are you sure you have the correct path? Also note that you can use maven's relative path for the target `<directory>src/main/java/</directory>`, which may be more convenient.

Comment: @wallek876 this saved me a lot of work. I had same config as OP but the weird thing is that `mvn clean package` worked fine but `mvn jooq-codegen:generate` didn't. I made your answer changes and everything works fine now. Thanks +1

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to [wallek876's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51284788/521799), you could rename your executionId to `default-cli` [as documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3449569/521799). So, this should work:

```xml
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>default-cli</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <!-- Configure the database connection here -->
            <jdbc>
            ...
```

Another option, which I always prefer, is to use profiles:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>jooq-codegen</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>3.11.2</version>
                    ...
```

And then, run that with

```
mvn install -P jooq-codegen
```

Comment: It gives the same output as `mvn -e jooq-codegen:generate`

Comment: Maven 3.5.4 running on Oracle Java 9. No dice.

Comment: @JamesHiew: Updated the answer