# Gradle --dry-run equivalent in maven

Tags: maven, gradle

Is there an equivalent to `./gradlew build --dry-run` which will show me all the tasks that will be executed when I run `./gradlew build`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven command to list lifecycle phases along with bound goals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709625/maven-command-to-list-lifecycle-phases-along-with-bound-goals)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a specific goal with a particular configuration in a Maven plugin when I have several configurations for that goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448648/how-do-i-run-a-specific-goal-with-a-particular-configuration-in-a-maven-plugin-w)